A coin lands on heads with probability $\frac1{9n+1}$ on $n-$th toss. What’s the probability it will land on heads eventually?
Question
Suppose there is a coin which lands on heads with probability $\frac1{9n+1}$ on $n-$th toss. What’s the probability it will land on heads eventually?
Reasoning
The answer can be given by the series $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(9n)!^9}{(9n+10)!^9},$$ where $!^9$ is the $9-$fold factorial (and $n$ is the number of previous tosses). Indeed, heads occur on the first toss with probability $\frac1{10}$, on the second toss with probability $\frac9{10}\cdot\frac1{19}$, on the third toss with probability $\frac9{10}\cdot\frac{18}{19}\cdot\frac1{28}$, and so on.
Does this series converge? How to evaluate it? Wolfram Alpha tells this series converges to $\frac{10\Gamma(\frac{10}9)}{9 \Gamma(\frac{19}9)}$. Why is that true? It’s clear that
$$\frac{10\Gamma(\frac{10}9)}{9 \Gamma(\frac{19}9)}=
\frac{10\Gamma(\frac{10}9)}{9 \Gamma(\frac{10}9+1)}=
\frac{10\Gamma(\frac{10}9)}{9 \cdot\frac{10}9\Gamma(\frac{10}9)}=1.$$
Another reasoning
We can consider the complements. The partial sum $\sum_{n=0}^{m-1}\frac{(9n)!^9}{(9n+10)!^9}$ is the probability that we have at least one heads on the first $m$ tosses. It is equal to $1$ minus the probability of all tails on the first $m$ tosses:
$$1-\frac9{10}\cdot\frac{18}{19}\cdot…\cdot\frac{9m}{9m+1}=1-\frac{(9m)!^9}{(9m+1)!^9}.$$
I would guess that $$\frac{(9m)!^9}{(9m+1)!^9}\sim cm^{-\frac{1}9}\underset{m\to\infty}{\to}0$$
by analogy with Stirling’s asymptotic formulae for double factorials, but I’m not sure. Wolfram Alpha tells that:
$$\frac{(9m)!^9}{(9m+1)!^9}=\frac{\Gamma(\frac{10}9)\Gamma(m+1)}{\Gamma(m+\frac{10}9)}.$$
Why is that true? If it’s true though, then
$$\frac{\Gamma(\frac{10}9)\Gamma(m+1)}{\Gamma(m+\frac{10}9)}=
\frac{\Gamma(\frac{10}9)\Gamma(m)\cdot m}{\Gamma(m+\frac{10}9)}= 
m \text B (m,\frac{10}9)\sim m\Gamma(\frac{10}9)m^{-\frac{10}9}=
\Gamma(\frac{10}9) m^{-\frac{1}9} \underset{m\to\infty}{\to}0.$$
And then indeed $$\sum_{n=0}^{m-1}\frac{(9n)!^9}{(9n+10)!^9} \underset{m\to\infty}{\to}1. $$

I was actually very close. From $$\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)$$ for a falling factorial $$(x)_k=x(x-1)…(x-k+1)$$ it follows that $$(x)_k = \frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{\Gamma(x-k+1)}.$$
Now $$\frac{(9m)!^9}{(9m+1)!^9}=\frac{9^m\cdot m!}{9^m\cdot(m+\frac19)_m} = \frac{\quad\Gamma(m+1)\quad}{\frac{\Gamma(m+\frac{10}9)}{\Gamma(\frac{10}9)}}=
\frac{\Gamma(\frac{10}9)\Gamma(m+1)}{\Gamma(m+\frac{10}9)}.$$
This tends to $0$ as I show in my original post. Or just by using $$\Gamma(x+a)\sim x^a\Gamma(x)$$
we immediately get $$\frac{\Gamma(\frac{10}9)\Gamma(m+1)}{\Gamma(m+\frac{10}9)}\sim \Gamma(\frac{10}9)\cdot m^{-\frac19}\underset {m\to\infty} \to0.$$
